# Regression: Should I use the prediction interval obtained given n=9 and an outlier (Cook's D= 0.558) present?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, outliers, small-sample, prediction-interval

The data I'm working with has 9 observations. I'm using only one predictor variable. Using SAS, I fit the model and checked the residuals. The typical model assumptions appear to be met, but there were two outliers. I wanted to see if a transformation would help. I used a boxcox macro, and it suggested an inverse transformation. I tried the transformation on both the dependent and independent variable. The model fit was improved with the latter. Now only one outlier remains (Cook's D=0.558).

I wanted to make a prediction for a particular value. Prediction intervals are already wide, and I don't know if given these circumstances it should even be looked at. Any advise and explanations?